# What move should I use to handle an attempt by the player to be stealthy?

Tags: powered-by-the-apocalypse, masks-a-new-generation

So, say my player is trying to surveil an enemy's base and 007s their way in there through the air vents to look around. This person is a Beacon and is not using any superpowers to do this.

For reference, I come from a D&D background where such a thing would be handled by a simple skill check, but no such mechanic exists in Masks.

There is obviously a chance for interesting failure here and an unknown outcome and so a dice roll seems to be very appropriate to handle the situation. However, none of the moves or anything else in the rules seem to cover what should be rolled here.

Is there something I'm missing that would be an obviously good way to do this?
Is this a case where I would need to create a move to handle the situation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is directly covered by Beacon's **Straight. Up. Creepin'.** move, if they have it. On a miss, give them trouble.

If they don't have that move, continue the conversation until a relevant move presents itself. Most likely, this will be them asking a question and you calling for **Assess the Situation**. If they're not being careful at all, make a hard move.

Note that if they picked *camouflage and stealth* as abilities and as long as that is relevant to the situation, you should give them quite a bit of leeway into their investigation of the place. They're skilled at doing this sort of thing.

As a reminder, look at the GM Moves regarding the Beacon, in particular,

- Draw attention to their inadequacies
- Make them pay for their audacity